# UILabel variable needs to be an Optional Double but I don't want the the label to display optional(valueOfNumber)

Tags: ios, swift, double, option-type, cs193p

I'm trying to complete the CS193P Course independently. I am on assignment 2 of the course and part of the assignment asks for me to do the following:

"Change the computed instance variable displayValue to be an Optional Double rather than a Double"

I was able to change `displayValue` to be an Optional Double, but now my UILabel which shows the `displayValue` now will display the optional value instead of the double value (which makes sense).

Example:

5 (then press enter) will display a value of Optional(5.0) in the UILabel.

Here is what I tried:

I determined that `result` and `displayValue!` will return a double.

I tried changing `display.text = result` to `display!.text! = result` but that did not fix the issue.

Here is a snippet of my code, I think you shouldn't need any more but please comment if you think I should show something else!

P.S. the name of the display is `display`

```
@IBAction func enter() {
    if let result = brain.pushOperand(displayValue!) {
        displayValue = result
    } else {
        displayValue = 0
    }
}

var displayValue: Double? {
    get {
        return NSNumberFormatter().numberFromString(display.text!)!.doubleValue
    }
    set{
        display!.text! = "\(newValue)"     //display is the UILabel
    }
```

Comment: The problem is that `newValue` is an optional that must be unwrapped when you create the label.  `display.text = "\(newValue!)"`.  Of course, that will crash if `displayValue` gets set to `nil`, so you should consider how you want to handle that.

Comment: Yes--I was planning on using an "if let" to handle that case of nil. I just wanted to figure out how to get it to display correctly first.     EDIT: Sorry--Just saw that you added an exclamation to "\newValue", that fixed my issue. Thanks for the advice

Comment: @vacawama any suggestions on how to handle the case of `nil`? I keep crashing :(. The professor in the video originally would have the `displayValue` equal zero in the case of `nil` but he said that was a bad way of doing it because it really should equal `nil`

Comment: I've watched earlier versions of those classes, just not the latest Swift ones. Prof. H is quite good. What do you want to happen in the case of nil. Set display to empty string? ""

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the display is supposed to be blank when, for example, the stack cannot be evaluated to give a result.

So you can just use

```
var displayValue: Double? {
    get { return NSNumberFormatter().numberFromString(display.text!)?.doubleValue }
    set { if newValue != nil { display.text = "\(newValue!)" }
            else { display.text = " " }
    }
}
```

And then for "enter"

```
@IBAction func enter() {
    if let dV = displayValue {
        brain.pushOperand(dV)
        displayValue = brain.evaluate()
    }
    userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber = false
}
```

This solution worked for me. I am working through this course independently too. It is tricky and I have to listen to the lectures LOTS of times :-)

Jacki